# SQL Server : merge two rows with same ID but different column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to merge different rows into one when they have the same id but different column values in Microsoft SQL Server.

For example, I have

```
ID     SubID          Desc
-----------------------------------
1      170            PC-money
1      171            PC-windows
2      170            PC-free
2      171            PC-open
```

I want to get this output:

```
ID     SubID          Desc                 Desc1
---------------------------------------------------    
1      170            PC-money             PC-free   
1      171            PC-windows           PC-open
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you want each column repeated for each duplicate? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

try it :

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,t1.subtype,t1.DESC ,t2.DESC  
FROM 
    table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN 
    table1 AS t2 
    ON t1.id != t2.id AND t1.subtype = t2.subtype
WHERE 
    t1.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`Conditional Aggregation` through grouping by `SubID` column might be used :

```
SELECT MIN([ID]) AS [ID], [SubID], 
       MAX(CASE WHEN [ID]=1 THEN [Desc] END) AS [Desc],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [ID]=2 THEN [Desc] END) AS [Desc1]
  FROM t
 GROUP BY [SubID]
```

or `pivot` might be used, alternatively :

```
SELECT t2.[ID], t1.[SubID], t1.[1] AS [Desc], t1.[2] AS [Desc1]
  FROM t
 PIVOT
 (
  MAX([Desc]) FOR [ID] IN ([1],[2])
 ) t1
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN([ID]) AS [ID] FROM t) t2
```

or consider picking the records with minimum ID values by use of `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT t2.[ID], t1.[SubID], t2.[Desc], t1.[Desc] AS [Desc1]
  FROM t AS t1
  LEFT JOIN t AS t2 
         ON t1.[ID] != t2.[ID] 
        AND t1.[SubID] = t2.[SubID]
 WHERE t2.[ID] IN ( SELECT MIN([ID]) FROM t )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=31e261cba3d5bd556c93fcc719cc3bdf)</kbd>

*P.S. `Desc` shouldn't be used without square-brackets of being a reserved keyword.*